# circular doubly linked list insertion at the end

Tags: c++, data-structures, doubly-linked-list, circular-list

I was going through dsa doubly circular list, and was practicing insertion of elements to it, after entering the first element my program ends abruptly.....is there a mistake in my insertafterfunction.i get a segmentation fault error .just help me through I cant find what has gone wrong..

```
#include<iostream>
struct Node{
    int data;
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
};
Node* headnode;    
void insert(int data){
    Node* newnode = new Node;
    newnode->data= data;
    newnode->next=headnode;
    newnode->prev=headnode;
    headnode=newnode;
}
void insertafter(int data){
    Node* newnode=new Node;
    newnode->data=data;
    newnode->next=headnode;
    Node* existingnode = headnode;
    while(existingnode->next!=headnode){
        existingnode=existingnode->next;
    }
    existingnode->next=newnode;
    newnode->prev= existingnode;
    headnode->prev=newnode;

}


void printnode(){
    Node* newnode=headnode;
    while (newnode->next!=headnode){
        std::cout<<newnode->data<<"->";
        newnode=newnode->next;
    }
    std::cout<<"\n";
 
}    
int main(){
    headnode=NULL;
    int x,data;
    std::cin>>x;
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        std::cin>>data;
        if(i==0)
        {
            insert(data);
        }
        else
        {
            insertafter(data);
        }
        printnode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example this while loop within the function `insertafter`

```
while(existingnode->next!=headnode){
    existingnode=existingnode->next;
}
```

invokes undefined behavior because after calling the function `insert` data members `prev` and `next` of the head node are equal to `nullptr`.

See the function insert

```
void insert(int data){
    Node* newnode = new Node;
    newnode->data= data;
    newnode->next=headnode;   // here headnode is equal to nullptr
    newnode->prev=headnode;   // And here headnode is equal to nullptr
    headnode=newnode;
}
```

It seems you mean at least the following function definition

```
void insert(int data){
    Node* newnode = new Node;
    newnode->data= data;
    headnode=newnode;
    newnode->next=headnode;
    newnode->prev=headnode;
}
```

That is after calling the function data members `prev` and `next` of the head node will point to the head node itself.

In general the separate function `insert` does not make a sense because it may be called (provided that it will be written correctly) only once.

Also the function `printnode` will output nothing if the list contains only the head node due to the condition in the while statement

```
    Node* newnode=headnode;
    while (newnode->next!=headnode){
```

Comment: so i should add headnode->next=newnode; headnode->prev=null; is that ryt bro??

Comment: @shyam0x See my updated post.